# CodeAcademy Car Rental II

Tags: python, if-statement

```
days = int(raw_input("How many days do you want to rent da car for?"))

def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days < 3:
        return days * 40
     elif days >= 3 and days <= 7:
        return ((days * 40)-20)
     elif days > 7:
         return ((days*40) -50)

print rental_car_cost(days)
```

I'm trying to figure out why the code doesn't give 230 when I use 7 for days. The problem seems to be in the 3rd if statement.

Comment: (7 * 40) - 20 = 260. Why are you expecting 230?

Comment: So far you are missing problem statement (you assume that everyone knows the problem and willing to search for it for you, which is not how SO works).

Comment: Side note: before adding back "thank you notes" to your post please check this discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1):

Your second if statement is triggering because you use <= in it (less than or equal to)

```
elif days >= 3 and days <= 7:
```

if you want the last one to trigger change it to < (less than) and the bottom one to >= (greater than or equal to)

```
elif days >= 3 and days < 7:
    return ((days * 40)-20)
 elif days >= 7:
```